# Aggregate only one of the duplicated values with groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, transform

I have the following data with the last column as the desired output:

| activity | teacher | group | students | the desired column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | A | a | 3 | 5 |
| One | B | b | 2 | 5 |
| two | A | c | 7 | 7 |
| One | D | a | 3 | 5 |
| two | C | c | 7 | 7 |

I want to group by the activity and returen the number of students without dublicate the student when we have more than one teacher for them.
I tried the following but it's dublicate the sum with for the same group.

```
df.groupby('activity').students.transform('sum')
```

the output of this looks like:

| activity | teacher | group | students | the output column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | A | a | 3 | 8 |
| One | B | b | 2 | 8 |
| two | A | c | 7 | 14 |
| One | A | a | 3 | 8 |
| two | C | c | 7 | 14 |

thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: 4th row of the teacher column. Should that be a "D" or an "A" ? The tables aren't identically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

```py
x = (
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=["activity", "group"])
    .groupby("activity")["students"]
    .sum()
)
df["the desired column"] = df["activity"].map(x)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  activity teacher group  students  the desired column
0      One       A     a         3                   5
1      One       B     b         2                   5
2      two       A     c         7                   7
3      One       D     a         3                   5
4      two       C     c         7                   7
```

Comment: That's what I gathered as well.

Comment: Thank you for your great and quick answer! it's really appreciated.. :)